# How should I account for the unpredictable value of RSUs when retirement planning?

Tags: stocks, retirement-plan, compensation

We are in the process of doing some heavy retirement math - figuring out when to target retirement, how much to invest, how much we will have to invest, etc.

Part of my compensation is in RSUs that are vested yearly.  These RSUs are traded on an exchange in another country.  Between the variable price of the stock and the variable value of the relative currencies, there is a lot of uncertainty around how much the RSUs will be worth during each vestment, and, as such, how much income they will generate that could be part of retirement math.

So far we have been ignoring the RSUs in our planning because of the unpredictability.  This will make for a fun surprise when they vest, but at the same time, we are perhaps less likely to put any income from them toward retirement.

Another approach would be worst case / most likely case / best case and assign odds to each of those, but that is still a bit of a guessing game.

Is there any mostly-good rule-of-thumb for factoring in such compensation when planning?

Comment: Are the RSUs that you get each year consistent in the amount of shares or total value? Meaning, do you get more shares if the value per share goes down (and vice-versa)? That would make it easier to plan.

Comment: It's consistent in the amount of shares